# Categorical variable in simple linear regression

Tags: regression, categorical-data, regression-coefficients, linear

I'm new to statistics. I have data that measures the effects of two different drugs (A and B) on the size of rabbits. The data consists of triplets $(\textrm{dose}, \mathrm{size}, \mathrm{type})$. I'm trying to run simple linear regression so that I could seperately get the slope (regression coefficient) of the drug A and the slope of the drug B. Then I'd like to run a test that compares the two slopes and tells me whether the difference between slopes is statistically significant. How should I go about doing this?

If it matters, exactly half of the collected data points are with the drug A and the other half is with the drug B. Any help or references would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: By "slope" do you mean the coefficient of dose?

Comment: That's correct, dose would be the independent variable, while size would be a dependent variable. My model would be $\mathrm{size} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot \mathrm{dose}$ and I'm looking for $\beta_1$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just include `dose*drug` in the model. The test of whether the `dose:drug` interaction effect is 0 is equivalent to the test of whether the coefficients of dose are the same for both drugs.

Specifically, let $Y_i$ be the size of the $i^{th}$ rabbit. Let $x_{i1}$ be the dose given to the $i^{th}$ rabbit. Let $x_{i2}$ be 0 if the $i^{th}$ rabbit gets drug A and 1 if it gets drug B. Assume the model
$$Y_i = \beta_0+\beta_1x_{i1} + \beta_2x_{i2} + \beta_3 x_{i1}x_{i2}+\epsilon_i,$$
where the $\epsilon_i$'s are iid $N(0,1)$.

Do a t-test of $H_0: \beta_3=0$ (e.g., via the summary output in R). Under $H_0$, the model reduces to
$$Y_i = \beta_0+\beta_1x_{i1} + \beta_2x_{i2} +\epsilon_i,$$
which implies that the effect of dose in each drug group is the same (namely, $\beta_2$).

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, I should run the model $\mathrm{size} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot \mathrm{dose} + \beta_2 \cdot \mathrm{dose} \cdot \mathrm{drug}$ over the whole data (where $\mathrm{drug}$ takes values $0$ and $1$) and then calculate $\beta_2$. So what would be the critical value for $\beta_2$ and why would this even work?

Comment: See edited version. The critical value would be based on the t-distribution with $n-4$ df, where $n$ is sample size.

Comment: Thanks again for your response and clear explanation. I'll accept your answer, but could you please provide a (primary) reference where I could read more about this? All google results are just medium articles.

Comment: STAT2: Modeling with Regression and ANOVA Second Edition, by Cannon et al. See Section 3.3, "Comparing Slopes".